# For repeating cards (multiple same tree structure ) in my html, is it recommended to put them in a list outline structure?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I've been contemplating within me whenever I have repeating tree structure in my html code whether to outline them using a list structure (using the `ul`/`ol` and `li` elements) or just use the casual `div`.

This is an illustration of the repeating tree structure I mean:

[image: the repeating tree structure image]

For the *list structure* I mean something like this:

```html
<ul class="features-card-container">
    <li class="feature-card-list-item">
        <h2>Quick Search Easily</h2>
        <p
            >search your snippets by content, category, web address,
            application, and more.</p
        >
    </li>
    <li class="feature-card-list-item">
        <h2>iCloud Sync</h2>
        <p>Instantly saves and syncs snippets across all your devices.</p>
    </li>
    <li class="feature-card-list-item">
        <h2>Complete History</h2>
        <p
            >Retrieve any snippets from the first moment you started using the
            app.</p
        >
    </li>
</ul>
```

and for the casual `div` structure, I mean:

```html
<div class="features-card-container">
    <div class="feature-card-divst-item">
        <h2>Quick Search Easily</h2>
        <p
            >search your snippets by content, category, web address,
            appdivcation, and more.</p
        >
    </div>
    <div class="feature-card-divst-item">
        <h2>iCloud Sync</h2>
        <p>Instantly saves and syncs snippets across all your devices.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="feature-card-divst-item">
        <h2>Complete History</h2>
        <p
            >Retrieve any snippets from the first moment you started using the
            app.</p
        >
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to know which of the two is recommended, or a better way to structure this.

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: @Paulie_D It's very related to web development. That's why I posted it here.

Comment: Not to make things even more complicated, but it seems to me that the screenshot you posted is in fact more similar to the use-case for a Description List, or `dl` element https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl

Comment: Yes but it's asking for opinions so regardless of whether its related to web development it's off-topic and so not allowed.

Comment: @Paulie_D Is it really an opinion? In my mind, using a `<ul>` structure for something that's intended to be a list is objectively better than just using a `<div>` because it gives more clarity to the structure (which of course helps with things that rely on that, such as screen readers). You could say which tag to use comes down to preference since it will work regardless, but there is still a correct answer—a `<ul>` is recommended.

Comment: Yes it's opinion, you are asking for a recommendation. Whether a `ul` or `dl` or div is best is asking for opinion. All are valid options but it's up to you to pick which is best for you.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, yes, it would be semantically correct to use an unordered list structure—it makes sense since it's a list of related items (i.e., a list of features apparently being offered). If you can reasonably call it a list, it's probably a good idea to use `<ul>`. Ultimately, it doesn't matter since using a simple `<div>` will work just as fine, but it seems you're asking about what would be more semantically appropriate, which does have more of an objective answer.